# Need some help trying to use ifelse and geocoded2 in R to make a map with different colored markers for different types of amphibians

Tags: r, if-statement, geocode

I am trying to make a map for my thesis of sampling sites of salamanders. I am super new to any of this so I don't really understand code much, but my advisor has given me a general outline of the code she has used before for something else that I am putting my stuff into. Where I am running into trouble is with the site markers for the types and their colors. I did manage to make an original map that I got to work but it only has frogs and salamanders, but I am trying to fix it to include toads and newts separately and with different colors.

Here is what I have been trying to do so far for the site markers on the map for each type of amphibian.

```
getColor <- ifelse(geocoded2$Type =="frog", "green")
                   ifelse(geocoded2$Type=="toad", "orange")
                   ifelse(geocoded2$Type=="salamander", "blue",
                   ifelse(geocoded2$Type=="newt", "purple"))
```

The error I am getting for these is:

```
Error in ifelse(geocoded2$Type == "frog", "green") : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

I got the map and legend to work, but just can't get the types to actually go through that are from my excel file
Here is what I used for the map & legend:

```
# create the map
map <- leaflet(geocoded2) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.OceanBasemap) %>%
  #addTiles() %>%  # use the default base map which is OpenStreetMap tiles
  fitBounds(-165,90,165,-90)%>%
  clearBounds()%>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(~Long, ~Lat, icon=icons, label=~Type) %>%
  addLegend("topright", colors= c("green", "blue", "red", "purple"), labels=c("Frog","Salamander", "toad", "Newt"), opacity=1 )

# plot the map
map
```

Comment: Instead of a long `ifelse` chain take a look at `case_when`.

Comment: As long as I remember, `ifelse` takes three arguments: 1) the conditional to test, 2) what to assign when conditional is true, 3) what to assign when conditional is false. You might be forgetting the third argument. As for @MartinGal 's comment above, `case_when` is part of tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the corrected ifelse version:

```
ifelse(geocoded2$Type =="frog", "green", 
ifelse(geocoded2$Type=="toad", "orange", 
ifelse(geocoded2$Type=="salamander", "blue",
       ifelse(geocoded2$Type=="newt", "purple"), "black")))
```

Or the easier to understand `case_when()` format:

```
library(dplyr)

getColor <- case_when(
   geocoded2$Type =="frog" ~ "green",
   geocoded2$Type=="toad" ~ "orange",
   geocoded2$Type=="salamander" ~ "blue",
   geocoded2$Type=="newt" ~ "purple",
   TRUE ~ "black"
)
```

Both method includes a default "black" color in case there are unexpected values in the input.